# Указатель на nil интерфейс в golang

Tags: golang, указатели, интерфейс

Имеется код

```
func ClearScreen(mode *int) string{
    mode = defaultValue(mode, 2).(*int)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%dK", CSI, *mode)
}

func defaultValue(arg *T, value T) *T{
    if arg == nil{
        arg = new(T)
        *arg = value
    }
    return arg
}
```

Функция *defaultValue* - используется не только с типом данных *int*, поэтому я объявил её, принимающей тип данных *T*(`type T interface{}`). Использую указатели, чтобы можно было делать так `ClearScreen(nil)`(то есть использовать значение аргумента `mode` по умолчанию)

Если это можно реализовать более очевидным способом, буду рад, если поможете. Если этот метод неплох, то как его доработать? Golang изучаю не так давно.

**P.S.**
CSI - строковая константа

Comment: Го не руби и не пайтон. Чем быстрее вы откажетесь от подобных конструкций, тем лучше. В го они крайне плохо приживаются и не приносят ничего, кроме страдания. Первый же приличный гофер перепишет этот код на что-то типа [этого](https://play.golang.org/p/OOI43GzNewb).

Comment: @Ainar-G, благодарю. Придётся писать кучу констант... эх

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написал [Ainar-G](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974538/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-nil-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%B2-golang?noredirect=1#comment1635840_974538), такие конструкции в Go нежелательны.
Переписанный код может выглядеть так:

```
const defaultMode = 2

// ClearScreen clears the screen. Use -1 for default mode.
func ClearScreen(mode int) string {
    if mode == -1 {
        mode = defaultMode
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%dK", CSI, mode)
}
```